# azure automl how to find best threshold in precision recall curve?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, threshold, precision-recall, automl

I use automl for a classification problem. I obtained the following precision recall curve:
[image]

Is it possible to find the best threshold that maximizes the f-score from this curve? and how?

Answer (score 0):

Using any kind of optimization mechanisms, we can improve the F1 score. In the below example I tried to reproduce with Standard Scalar optimization mechanism.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression as lrs
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pipeline = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), lrs(random_state=1))
# Create training test splits using two features
#
pipeline.fit(X_train[:,[2, 13]],y_train)
probs = pipeline.predict_proba(X_test[:,[2, 13]])
fpr1, tpr1, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, probs[:, 1], pos_label=1)
roc_auc1 = auc(fpr1, tpr1)

#
# Create training test splits using two different features
#
pipeline.fit(X_train[:,[4, 14]],y_train)
probs2 = pipeline.predict_proba(X_test[:,[4, 14]])
fpr2, tpr2, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, probs2[:, 1], pos_label=1)
roc_auc2 = auc(fpr2, tpr2)
#
# Create training test splits using all features
#
pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)
probs3 = pipeline.predict_proba(X_test)
fpr3, tpr3, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, probs3[:, 1], pos_label=1)
roc_auc3 = auc(fpr3, tpr3)
 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.5, 7.5))
 
plt.plot(fpr1, tpr1, label='ROC Curve 1 (AUC = %0.2f)' % (roc_auc1))
plt.plot(fpr2, tpr2, label='ROC Curve 2 (AUC = %0.2f)' % (roc_auc2))
plt.plot(fpr3, tpr3, label='ROC Curve 3 (AUC = %0.2f)' % (roc_auc3))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', color='red', label='Random Classifier')   
plt.plot([0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], linestyle=':', color='green', label='Perfect Classifier')
plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False positive rate')
plt.ylabel('True positive rate')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

[image]

With Standard Scaler we will get the maximum in F1 score with the max of AUC.